# Command not support

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop

I need some advise and suggestion on my problem below:

Currently i have java card that run JCOP OS. then, I need to develop java card applet and load inside the card.

However i got stuck when i need to set my CLA to support CC/C8 commands. e.g. CC50000000..and i got return SW 0x6881. When i google on this error, i found that the issue is due to the Logical Channel.

So, my question is there any way that i can do to allow JCOP to support the CLA CC/C8 command?

Your guy help on this matter is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Neither C8 nor CC indicate use of a logical channel (except of the basic channel, which always exists), so how sure are you about the SW?

Comment: Sorry, i dont get what u mean..as far as i knew, both CLA is non standard GP or ISO CLA command..probably the applet is not comply with the GP or ISO specification

Comment: Even if CLA byte indicates proprietary, its structure as defined in ISO 7816-4 should apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CC/C8 indicates the basic logical channel and the command indicates an initialize update command. On which application, you are sending this command ? may be there is a faulty implementation in that application.

Comment: Sorry for make you confuse from my sample command..actually the INS is not 50..the sample above only the INS is not 50..but 00 and 32..